# How to merge many rows into one oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table a such that

Select * From a where person id =1; returns

```
person_id  colA colB

1           AA   BB

1           CC   DD

1           EE   FF
```

Now what i need is

```
person_id colA colB colA_row_2, colB_Row_2  ColA_row_3 ColB_ROW_3

1          AA   BB  CC           DD           EE         FF
```

I will always get nine rows per person.  So i can just create the columns as non dynamic but cant seem how to do it.  This needs to be in pure sql no stored procedures.  Thanks in advance

Comment: It doesn't matter if you get 1-AA-BB-CC-DD-EE-FF or 1-CC-DD-EE-FF-AA-BB, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use decode as an alternative.

[https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4471013000346257238](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:4471013000346257238)

Answer (score 2):

You need PIVOT for the query
See the examples http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html and http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php

You have to define how rows are converted into columns
e.g.

```
pivot 
(
   count(colA )
   for colA in ('AA' as "AA",'CC' "CC"...)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using

select
 MAX(DECODE(ROWNUM, 1, AA, NULL)) AA,....
 MAX(DECODE(ROWNUM, 1, FF, NULL)) COLB_ROW_3 FROM (SELECT .....);